# App crashed when give back action continuously - shared preference error android

Tags: java, android

I have to do back action continuously, app crashed. It shows:

"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference"

And another thing, I have shared preference class individually. When I need to get strings from shared preference, I have to add get preference object in on create function in my activity.